# Are primitive data types in PHP passed by reference?

Tags: php, performance, byref

In PHP, I'm frequently doing lots of string manipulation. Is it alright to split my code into multiple functions, because if primitive types like strings are passed by value I would be significantly affecting performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only objects are passed by reference.

That doesn't mean you'll get a performance boost by changing to references though - PHP uses copy-on-write, so a copy is only made if you modify the variable.

Splitting your code into functions won't slow it down from that point of view.
There is a small overhead for calling a function, but unless your in a loop calling 10,000s of them it's probably not something you need to worry about.

Comment: Objects are not passed by reference.  Objects are reference types, but they are passed by value as function parameters unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: They're not technically passed by reference but close enough.  This is true as of PHP 5 - PHP 4 was different.

Answer (score 2):

Objects are passed by reference. Everything else is passed by value unless you explicitly use [pass-by-reference with the & operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

That being said, PHP also uses [copy-on-write](http://blog.golemon.com/2007/01/youre-being-lied-to.html) to avoid unnecessary copying.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, primitives are passed by value unless you explicitly define the function to pass by reference (by using an ampersand `&` in front of the parameter) or invoke the function with an ampersand in front of the argument. (The latter of which is deprecated)

See [this part of the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) for more.

EDIT

Also, the statement that "objects are passed by reference" in PHP is a bit of a simplification, though it can often be thought of that way for most purposes.  This [chapter of the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) explains the differences.

Answer (score 1):

By default, everything is passed by value.  If you want to pass something by reference you have to explicitly state it as so.

Here is the [php documentation that explicitly states this behavior](http://phpbuilder.com/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

Answer (score 1):

Passing by reference is actually slower than passing by value in PHP. I can't find the correct citation for this claim; it's somewhere in the "References" section of the PHP manual.